# Call function by pointer and set parametrs in memory block

Tags: c++, c

I've little problem :

I'm solving problem with calling function by pointer and passing to it parameters in continuous memory block. 
  My goal is to have function named e.g

```
CallFunc(void * func,void *params, unsigned int param_length);
```

that I'll send function pointer, pointer to function's parameters and eventually parameters length and this calling function will call passed function with it's parameters.

I will like write this in C/C++, but if somebody has idea, how this resolve in other language, that supports DLL generation and exportet functions, it will be fine too.

Thanks for answers,
  Ellesmess

P.S. > I'm sorry about my English, but I'm Czech, thanks :o)

Comment: Function pointers in Java tend to put me in LOL mode. Anyway, to say things simple, it's not possible in java (this is why I removed the tag).

Comment: What does this have to do with python or pascal

Comment: Pascla or python can have tools to solve this problem. Can pascal or Pyhton call function by pointer with all arguments in one array?

Comment: python has a builtin mechanism to call function with an unknown number of arguments, which is well-docuemented: `def call(func, args): func(*args)` will call function `func` passing it all elements of the list `args` as if they were arguments. this is no magic and is covered in any python tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, another try :)
Again I'm not sure this is what you need + I believe that you need to change your code style(because from your question I'm filling that you are doing something vary strange).

And here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
using namespace std;

template <typename Ret>
void CallFunc(boost::function<Ret ()> func)
{
    func();
}


template< typename Ret, typename Arg1>
Ret CallFunc(boost::function<Ret (Arg1)> func, void * args[])
{
    Arg1 * arg1= static_cast<Arg1*> (args[0]);
    return func(*arg1);
}

template<typename Ret, typename Arg1,typename Arg2>
Ret CallFunc(boost::function<Ret (Arg1,Arg2)> func, void * args[])
{
    Arg1 * arg1= static_cast<Arg1*> (args[0]);
    Arg2 * arg2= static_cast<Arg2*> (args[1]);
    return func(*arg1,*arg2);
}

int somefunction(int x)
{
    return x*x;
}


int main()
{
    boost::function<int (int)> func(somefunction);
    int x=17;
    void * args[1];
    args[0]=&x;
    int y = CallFunc(func,args );

    std::cout<<y<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm.... thats look nice....but - I tried to compile this code (without boost::), but I got this error mesage from compiler : variable or field 'CallFunc' declared void. I have MinGW32 (gcc) compiler and QT creator. What is that error?

Comment: @Ellesmess Glain Well you need boost library :) http://www.boost.org (need to install and include <boost/function.hpp>. If you don't want to use other liberarys just write your own function class. Ask me if you have any questions :).

Comment: If it isn't needed to solve this problem, I vote for write own function class, but I'm relatively new in C++ and I don't now how :-[. And... I thank you for maybe functional solution :o)

Comment: Okay, I've compiled code and I've another question - how about return values? Can I handle return value (variety or one type)?

Comment: @Ellesmess Glain I changed my code, so it's now returning value :)

Comment: And last thing - can I store abstract pointer to this func? I want create struct like this : struct { char code[4]; void *func; unsigned char par_length; };. Goal of this is to pass func to CallFunc... is it possible?

Comment: It crossed my mind, that this code don't support variadic functions as printf, I'm sure...?

Comment: @Ellesmess Glain sorry I don't understand what you want to do. Could you bring some example?

Comment: @Ellesmess Glain Yes it's not supporting variadic functions.

Comment: If I want call CallFunc, I must have original definition of func (boost::function<int (int)>). But if I want universal holder for calling thins functions, I can't store there func, becaouse it is of type boost::function<void (char,yy)>. Is something hiearchical most highly, to what I can store func? I want to create something as instuctions, where will be (code,funcptr,arguments). And this "instruction" may be argument for CallFunc (this cannot have any castings :-( )... it is quiet chaotic.... I'm sorry

Comment: Well it's to chaotic. Question what is code? And also I'm not sure what you want to do, but you can declare template structure with boost::function member instead void * func. And again. Are you sure your are coding correct thing? I'm afraid you are saying something very very very strange and chaotic as you say :(.

Comment: I want to have e.g. this function : boost::function<int (int)> func(somefunction); and this function boost::function<int (int,my_struct)> func2(somefunction); and some variable, that is able to store both of this funcs (func and func2), something like fp = func; CallFunce(fp,...); fp = func2; CallFunc(fp,...);. unfortunately, my problem is very strange :o(

Comment: @Ellesmess Glain I suggest you open new topic and explain what you want. It is really very hard to understand what you need from 2 lines of comment. So please open new topic. I will answere there :)

Comment: I created new topic here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722936/script-engine-calling-unknown-funcs

Answer (score 0):

Well without knowing what type are your parameters it's not possible to restore them from void*. So it's not possible.
 You need to change your CallFunc interface.

I'm not sure that it's what you need but it is working.

```
template <typename Func>
void CallFunc(Func func)
{
    func();
}

template <typename Func, typename  Arg1_Type>
void CallFunc(Func func,Arg1_Type arg1)
{
    func(arg1);
}

template <typename Func, typename  Arg1_Type, typename  Arg2_Type>
void CallFunc(Func func,Arg1_Type arg1,Arg2_Type arg2)
{
    func(arg1,arg2);
}


//defination of CallFunc untill Arg10 or Arg20 
.....


//some function

void somefunction(int x)
{
std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
}

//and calling it in main

CallFunc(somefunction,7);
```

Comment: It's nice, but it don't help me, becaouse only way, how I can pass argument to this function, is one argument with all parameters. I hope, that can be solvable in high language with low level knowgledges as storing arguments on stack and then calling function...

Comment: @Ellesmess Glan Is there any set of types, that your arguments can be, or they can be of any type?

Comment: Arguments hasn't defined type. They have only length. Called function will know, what it have on input

Answer (score 0):

C++0x has variadic templates, which allow this kind of magic:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

template<typename... Args> void CallFunc (void (*func)(Args...), Args... args) {
  func (args...) ;
}

void f (int x, double y) { cout << x << ", " << y << endl ; }

int main() { CallFunc (&f, 123, 5.6) ; }
```

Comment: I know about this, but again compared to original post - I can't pass arguments separated by commas, I only can pass all arguments in one :o(. Something as add(int a, int b) ... callfunc(add,(5)(8),8); where (5)(8) are ints stored int void*